# Рекурсивный алгоритм ввода двумерного массива

Tags: рекурсия, массивы, алгоритм

Здравствуйте. Скажите, а можно ли алгоритм ввода двумерного массива реализоавать как рекурсивный.

Comment: @Unforgiven, к ответам (демонстрирующим -- МОЖНО!) добавлю, что даже существует теорема, доказывающая эквивалентность итераций и рекурсии.

Comment: @avp тогда уж ссылку в студию - было бы любопытно взглянуть. Честно говоря, не знал, что это так

Comment: @DreamChild, я про нее только слышал, конечно (уже не помню где именно в первый раз), но не изучал и не доказывал.  

Однако, гугл тут же нашел [Теорема 5.1   Любой алгоритм, реализованный в рекурсивной форме, может быть переписан в итерационном виде, и наоборот.](http://www.ctc.msiu.ru/materials/Book/node32.html) + кучу других ссылок.

Только вот, очевидно, что практической пользы от такого знания мало.

Comment: @avp спасибо) Впрочем, на практическую пользу от нее я и не рассчитывал - просто что-то любопытное из разряда "удивительное рядом"

Comment: Рекурсивно можно многое написать, только не нужно. Такую простую вещь слишком медленно выполнять будет

Answer (score 2):

Любой итеративный алгоритм можно переделать в рекурсивный. Более того, в функциональных языках с рекурсией работать удобнее.

Более-более того, в генераторах компиляторов, таких как **yacc** «ввод» данных организован как раз через рекурсию:

```
двумерный_массив  : одномерный_массив '\n' двумерный_массив
                  | одномерный_массив
                  |
                  ;

одномерный_массив : элемент ',' одномерный_массив
                  | элемент
                  |
                  ;
```

Но в императивных языках *родной* конструкцией является вложенный цикл.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Вот пример на C#:

```
    // рекурсивное заполнение одномерного массива
    public static int[] Fill(int[] arr, int index = 0)
    {
        if (index < arr.Length)
        {
            arr[index] = index;
            Fill(arr, index + 1);
        }

        return arr;
    }

    //по аналогии для двумерного
    static int[][] Fill2D(int[][]arr, int index = 0)
    {
       if (index < arr.Length)
        {
            arr[index] = Fill(arr[index]);
            Fill2D(arr, index + 1);
        }

       return arr;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int[][] arr = new int[5][];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = new int[5];

        arr = Fill2D(arr);

        foreach (var i in arr)
        {
            foreach (var item in i)
                Console.Write("{0} ", item);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Добавлю, что спецификатор параметров по умолчанию разрешен только с использованием framework 4.0+. Т.е. на framework 3.5 конструкция 

    static int[][] Fill2D(int[][]arr, int index = 0)

int index *= 0*

не пройдет

Comment: @pincher1519 во-первых, параметры по умолчанию добалены исключительно из соображений перфекционизма, и ни малейшего значения для самого алгоритма они не несут. Следовательно, их при желании можно убрать вообще без малейшего вреда программе. А во-вторых, в вопросе вообще нет привязки к конкретному языку (и уж тем более к его версии)

Comment: @dreamchild, я ни коем образом не пытался вас обидеть, а лишь дополнил ваш код информацией, чтобы после не появилось вопроса, почему код не компилится в 2008 студии.

Answer (score -1):

что-то вроде такого:

```
void recursive(int **mas, size_t i, size_t j, size_t w, size_t h)
{
    if (i <= w)
        recursive(mas, i, j+1, w, h);
    printf("%d %d:", w-i, w-j);

    int n = 0;
    sscanf("%d", n);
    mas[w-i][w-j] = n;
    if (j == h) { 
        j = 0;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверяли, прежде чем такое написать?

Comment: @Veliant segmentation fault тащемта